# create dynamic url in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-urlmanager

my rules config is:

```
[
    'pattern' => 'admin/post',
    'route' => 'admin/default/post',
],
```

it's work! when open `http://example.com/admin/post` show `admin/default/post` for me,

but when i want create dynamic url with this code:

```
echo \yii\helpers\Url::to('/admin/default/test');
```

output is `http://example.com/admin/default/test`

who to create a dynamic url correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `Url::to()`

> This method is very similar to `[[toRoute()]]`. The only difference is
>   that this method
>         requires a route to be specified as an array only. If a string is given, it will be treated as a URL.

You need to pass an `array` rather than string

```
\yii\helpers\Url::to(['/admin/default/test']);
```